# Live JSON stream in a table

Tags: javascript, json, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to live stream data from JSON to a table which shows data in FILO format (First In Last Out) on a responsive web app.
The sample is at Latest Ride posted on http://www.zimride.com/

Searching web for this solution and tried various JS frameworks,but with no joy . This comes close to what I want to achieve --> http://www.bootply.com/63147

Can someone help me provide pointers?

Comment: Havent you tried doing the actually data pull coding at all? what frameworks did you try to use? I personally work with Backbone most of the time, it could fit your specs. A great documentation could be find here http://backbonejs.org . Try reading about model fetching and notice the example given there (fetching every x seconds)

Comment: I tried bootstrap to do it , but I guess its not the best fit . I am exploring backbone.js ...

Comment: You can use them both alongside - each of them has a completely different purpose.

Comment: looking at backbone.js v/s Angular.js which is preferred any code snippet would be really helpful

Comment: [SOLVED] The easiest way for me to do this is using jQUERY http://api.jquery.com/animateStartup it DOM manipulation and its works.